# How to scale an image saved as byte array?

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap, scaling

When you have an image (PNG in this case) saved as byte array on android, how can scale it to get a new image scaled in byte array format?

Have in mind that the image to scaling is to a smaller size, avoiding loss of data.

Answer (score 1):

Image croping byte uri image convert byte array the step
 InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
   byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);

Answer (score 0):

One quick way of doing this, it's letting Android to resolve the algorithm for us.
So, we convert the byte array to a bitmap, the bitmap can create a new bitmap with new sizes defined and finally convert back to byte array.

```
private byte[] getScaledImage(byte[] originalImage, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    // PNG has not losses, it just ignores this field when compressing
    final int COMPRESS_QUALITY = 0;

    // Get the bitmap from byte array since, the bitmap has the the resize function
    Bitmap bitmapImage = (BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(originalImage, 0, originalImage.length));

    // New bitmap with the correct size, may not return a null object
    Bitmap mutableBitmapImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage,newWidth, newHeight, false);

    // Get the byte array from tbe bitmap to be returned
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mutableBitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , outputStream);

    if (mutableBitmapImage != bitmapImage) {
        mutableBitmapImage.recycle();
    } // else they are the same, just recycle once

    bitmapImage.recycle();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: wait, you ask the question and 30 seconds after you write the answer? is it valid?

Comment: Hi, You can post the question with one answer you have already... it does not mean that someone else cannot post another better answer.

Comment: @diegoveloper Yes, it's allowed. This is a Q&A site. No matter who posts a question and who answers it. Unless both the question and the answer are valid.

Comment: what about if the question is duplicated?